# How can I remove 1/2" PVC pipe that has broken off inside a 1/2" elbow?

Tags: pipe, pvc

How can I remove 1/2" PVC pipe that has broken off inside a 1/2" elbow?

Comment: A photo might help, but usually the right answer is to cut away both sides and splice in new pieces...

Answer (score 1):

You know what they say: *nothing is forever -- except glued PVC parts*. Well I don't know if they really say that but they should.

It's unclear exactly what situation you have, but if you have a glued part that is broken, the only option is to cut out the elbow and replace it with a new one. You might need to use a coupling to add on another 1" or so of pipe to get the elbow positioned correctly again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool for drilling out fittings called the ram bit: https://www.plumbingsupply.com/rambit-plastic-fitting-saver-tool.html